# Finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{O})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups

What are the finite subgroups (subloops that are groups) of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{O})$? In particular, are there any not contained in a $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{H})$?

Comment: What do you mean by $SL_2({\mathbb O})$? (I know what $SL_2({\mathbb H})$ is.) As far as I know, this object does not exist as a group.

Comment: It is not a group, but it is a loop.

Comment: I don't think this is a commonly known object, perhaps you could add a definition or at least give a reference where a definition can be read? Depending on that, your Moufang loop may or may not contain $Spin(9,1)$ and/or a group related to $G_2$. Either would then contain finite subgroups not contained in a $SL_2(\mathbb{H})$.